# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, cors, omniauth, access-control

I am trying to use omniauth to direct my client to an external services authorization page. My client uses ember.js and my server is a rails server. As things stand, I am able to make the call with little problem on my server side, but my client will not redirect, thoring me an error reading

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

Doing some research has shown that I need to use CORS, which I have installed and configured. Now I just need to know where and how I apply the `access-control-allow-origin` header to my code. Can anyone help me with this problem?

my route:

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
```

my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @request.env
    auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    Account.recieve_donation(auth)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you will have to do If you are making GET request, your client request have to send **Origin header** and then your server have to send the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin header** in the response. **Values of both of these header have to be the same to allow cross origin resource sharing**.

Comment: Where do I add the `Origin` header client side and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header serverside? What exactly should they be? If I am able to start the request phase, does that mean I am already good re:Access-Control-Allow-Origin serverside?

Comment: I don't use Ember and rails, but in all languages and frontend frameworks  when you make a get request you can specify some extra headers with the request and similarly in the rails you can set headers while sending the response.

Comment: hmm so then it's really just a question of grammar at this point in time. How would you do this in a frontend framework/back end MVC framework you are familiar with? I imagine that that will at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: In AngularJS we set it as $http.get('www.google.com/someapi', { headers: {'Origin': 'abc.com'} }); At back end with Node.js var options = {
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/request/request',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'abc.com'
  }
};

Comment: Check Ember and Rails on how to set headers in request and response

Comment: So whenever I try and set the Origin header on my front end, I get thrown a message reading `Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"`. I think this is because I am working on a local host and chrome is finicky about them. Do you know How I could deal with this?

Comment: Try in Firefox and see the console output

Comment: I think Origin header will be set automatically by browser you just have to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header at server

Comment: Hmm, so this is a pretty good answer for 'what do I need to do', I just need to figure out how I am going to do it. Probably going to open up a separate question for this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a ruby gem [Rack CORS Middleware](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to solve the 'Access-control-allow-origin' header problem.

---

If you don't want to use ruby gem, add the following code in your controller(application_controller, other_name_controller)

```
    before_action :allow_cross_domain_access
after_action :cors_set_access_control_headers

def allow_cross_domain_access
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'# http://localhost:9000
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With X-CSRF-Token}.join(',')
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
end
def cors_set_access_control_headers
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = %w{Origin Accept Content-Type X-Requested-With X-CSRF-Token}.join(',')
        headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end
```